# Add row_number to maximum value

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

This is a simplified version of my problem (and I couldn't come up with an example that makes sense in real-life).

Assume I have a Table Person

Table Person

```
ID       Name        Number     Category
1        Follett     null       Thriller
2        Rowling     null       Fantasy
3        Martin      80         Fantasy
4        Cage        55         Thriller
5        Baldacci    null       Thriller
```

Now I want to get the following Result:

```
ID       Name        Number     Category
1        Follett     56         Thriller
2        Rowling     81         Fantasy
3        Martin      80         Fantasy
4        Cage        55         Thriller
5        Baldacci    57         Thriller
```

1. Group by Category
2. Select the maximum Number Value of each Category
3. Add the row_number (partitioned by the Category) to that number and set the new value, (edit:) BUT only for Numbers that where null before.

The parts I have so far (NOT WORKING, more to illustrate what I'd like to do, I do know why this can't possibly work)

```
UPDATE Person P
SET Number = sub.current + sub.row
FROM (
  SELECT
   Id,
   max(Number) as current,
   (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Category)) AS row
  FROM Person
  GROUP BY Category
) as sub
WHERE P.Id = sub.Id
```

Note: For the corner case where all Numbers are null for a Category the max(Number) should just be 0 and the new values should simply be the row_numbers().

I am using Postgresql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value in a `select` using:

```
select p.*,
       (coalesce(max(number) over (partition by category), 0) +
        row_number() over (partition by category order by number)
       ) as newnumber
from person p;
```

You can then put this in an `update` statement as:

```
update person
    set number = pp.newnumber
    from (select p.*,
           (coalesce(max(number) over (partition by category), 0) +
            row_number() over (partition by category order by number)
           ) as newnumber
          from person p
         ) pp
    where pp.id = p.id and p.number is null;
```

As a note:  If you are attempting to create a unique value doing this, it might not work.  The sequential numbers for a particular category might conflict with the numbers from another category.  If this is what you are trying to do, then ask another question with more details.

Comment: wow, that was fast! the numbers only have to be unique for each category, not overall (I am just trying your solution now)

Comment: I noticed a problem that I didn't specify in my simplified question. I'll quickly update the question to include the "new requirement". Sorry about that.

Comment: @taranaki . . . That just needs a `coalesce()`.  Actually, as I just wrote it, the values will start at 1 rather than 0.  You can put in `-1` instead of `0` to start at 0.

Comment: hi Gordon. Unfortunately there is still a small problem :/ The row_number() is too high because all rows are considered and not just the ones with null values. So the numbers are not continuous... I can fix the issue by adding an "order by number DESC".